# Remove textField listner in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, listener, textfield

how can I disable/remove the control listener for a `textField` in flutter, I am using 3 `textField` connected with a simple math.. (**textField1 + textField2 = textField3**) & (**textField1 - textField3 = textField2**)... I need to change the value of **textField3** & keep the value of textField2 unchanged?. the current situation is like this
[image]
This is my Code

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focus.addListener(() {
      if (_focus.hasFocus) {
        _finalValue.clear();
      }
    });
    _focuselocity.addListener(() {
      if (_focuselocity.hasFocus) {
        velocityEditingController.clear();
      }
    });
    textEditingController.addListener(() => setState(() {}));
    velocityEditingController.addListener(() => setState(() {
          totalCalculated();
        }));
    _finalValue.addListener(() => setState(() {
          totalCalculated();
        }));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    velocityEditingController.removeListener(() {
      totalCalculated();
    });
    textEditingController.removeListener(() {
      totalCalculated();
    });
    _finalValue.removeListener(() {
      totalCalculated();
    });
  }

  String totalCalculated() {
    airFlowText = textEditingController.text;
    velocityText = velocityEditingController.text;
    finalText = _finalValue.text;

    if (airFlowText != '' && velocityText != '' && !_focus.hasFocus) {
      sam = (int.parse(airFlowText) + int.parse(velocityText)).toString();
      lastVelocityValue = velocityText;
      _finalValue.value = _finalValue.value.copyWith(
        text: sam.toString(),
      );
    }
    if (airFlowText != '' && finalText != null && !_focuselocity.hasFocus) {
      sam = (int.parse(airFlowText) - int.parse(finalText)).toString();
      velocityEditingController.value =
          velocityEditingController.value.copyWith(
        text: sam.toString(),
      );
    }
    return sam;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove a listener you must provide exact instance of that function. In your code you are creating new functions every time so Dart don't really see that these are "equal".

The easiest way to ensure that you are using the same instance is to put your function as a state method.

```dart
  void _onVelocityChanged() {
    setState(() {
      totalCalculated();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    velocityEditingController.addListener(_onVelocityChanged);
    // ...
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    velocityEditingController.removeListener(_onVelocityChanged);
  }
```

Please also note that rather than removing listeners on `dispose` you should call `dispose` on TextEditingControllers, which effectively removes listeners.